# Show that $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2}+2}{(x^{3}-1)^{1/3}}dx$ diverges as per p-test for Type II Improper Integrals.

Tags: limits, improper-integrals

$$I=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2}+2}{(x^{3}-1)^{1/3}}dx\\\tag{1}$$

Considering the P-test for Type-II requirement for Improper Integrals:

For a $f(x)$ unbounded at $a$, Let $\lim_{x \to a+} (x-a)^pf(x)=K$. Then,

1. $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ converges if $p<1$ and $K$ is finite.
2. $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ diverges if $p\ge1$ and $K\neq0$.

Here is what I have done:

As $I$ is unbounded at $a=1$ and improper at $b=\infty$ hence we do two steps here,

Step # 1:

Taking $\lim_{x \to 1+} (x-1)^pf(x)=K$ i.e.,

$$\lim_{x \to 1+} (x-1)^p \frac{(x^{2}+2)}{(x^{3}-1)^{1/3}}$$

$$\lim_{x \to 1+} (x-1)^{1/3} \frac{(x^{2}+2)}{(x-1)^{1/3}(x^{2}+x+1)^{1/3}}=3^{2/3}=K$$

Hence $K$ is finite & $p=1/3$ (p$<1$) so limit converges for $f(x)$ at lower bound $a=1$. So $I$ for $f(x)$ converges at $a=1$.

Step # 2:

For this step, $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ I'm confused how to proceed.

Also I know that (by other methods CAS etc) Integral $I$ doesn't converge. May be the problem is I am testing the p-test for convergence of Type II integral only on lower bound which is unbounded. Although upper bound is also $\infty$ hence how can I prove that the $I$ diverges ? What I am missing here ?

Comment: The test you describe appears designed for finite $a$ only. Do you know a variant for $a=\infty$? If so, try using it to show $\frac{x^2+2}{(x^3-1)^{1/3}}\sim x$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @J.G. Yes by simply doing "comparison test" $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2}+2}{(x^{3}-1)^{1/3}}$ where $g(x)=\frac{x^{2}}{x}$ in $f(x)\ge g(x)\ge0$ for all $x\ge0$. Then $\int_{a}^{\infty} x dx = \lim_{x \to \infty} x^{2}/2$ becomes $\infty$ hence $\int_{a}^{\infty} g(x) dx$ diverges so $\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ diverges also. But I'm not sure this test is applicable as p-test for Type II improper integral.

Comment: To study the convergence at $+\infty$, you can change the variable in the integral $t=1/x$. The integral becomes $\int_0^1 \frac{1+2t^2}{t^3(1-t^3)^{1/3}}dt$ and the integrals are of the same nature.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette you meant $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1+2t^{2}}{t(1-t^{3})^{1/3}}dt$ ?

Comment: I didn't make a mistake. To change variable in practice, we write $t = 1 / x$ i.e. $x = 1/t$ hence $dx = (1 / t)' dt$ and thus $dx = - (1 / t^2) dt$ and we get $\int_1^0 \frac{1/t^2 + 2}{(1 / t^3-1)^{1/3}} \left (- \frac{1}{t^2} \right) dt$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

If you expand the integrand as series, you have

$$\frac{x^{2}+2}{(x^{3}-1)^{1/3}}=\frac{3^{2/3}}{\sqrt[3]{x-1}}+\frac{(x-1)^{2/3}}{\sqrt[3]{3}}+\frac{2 (x-1)^{5/3}}{3   \sqrt[3]{3}}+O\left((x-1)^{7/3}\right)$$ so no problem at the lower bound but
$$\frac{x^{2}+2}{(x^{3}-1)^{1/3}}=x+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{1}{3 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$

So, no problem for
$$\int_1^p \frac{x^{2}+2}{(x^{3}-1)^{1/3}}\,dx$$ as long as $p$ is finite.

Comment: Ofcourse, but as per original question, p (or b) is infinite.